# NodeJS Bluebird promise created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, bluebird

I have the following nodejs code as an express middleware function

```
Middleware.is_authenticated = function(req, res, next)
{
    if(req.system_session == undefined || req.system_session.login_status == false) return res.status(401).send({errors: true, error: 'invalid_session', session: req.system_session}).end();

    Session.validate_session(req.system_session, req.ip, req.headers['user-agent'])

    .then(function(session)
    {
        return next();
    })

    .catch(function(err)
    {
        req.system_session.destroy();
        return res.status(401).send({errors: true, error: err.message, session: req.system_session}).end();
    });
};
```

My Session.validate_session code:

```
Session.validate_session = function(user, user_ip, user_agent)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        if(user.user_id == null || user.user_name == null || user.user_rank == null || user.user_session == null || user_ip == null || user_agent == null) return reject(new Error('invalid_session'));

        new api_session({user_session: user.user_session}).fetch({columns: ['user_id', 'user_name', 'user_rank', 'user_session', 'user_ip', 'user_agent']})

        .then(function(result)
        {
            if(result == null) return reject(new Error('invalid_session'));

            return result.toJSON();
        })

        .then(function(session)
        {
            if(session == null || session.user_id != user.user_id || session.user_name != user.user_name || session.user_rank != user.user_rank || session.user_ip != user_ip || session.user_agent != user_agent) return reject(new Error('invalid_session'));

            return resolve(session);
        })

        .catch(function(err)
        {
            return reject(err);
        });
    });
};
```

Everything is working exactly as it should, everything is executing flawlessly with the database, as well as resolving the 'next' route and even displaying the response. But no matter what I try I keep getting 'a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it'

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler at middleware.js:12:11 but was not returned from it

at new Promise (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
at Object.Permission.permission_list (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/app/security/permission.js:8:10)
at PermissionService.permission_list (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/app/http/services/permission_service.js:6:14)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at /Users/Bill/Documents/app/app/http/middleware.js:12:11
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

From previous event:
at Middleware.is_authenticated (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/app/http/middleware.js:10:4)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at clientSession (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-sessions.js:630:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at SendStream.error (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at SendStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
at SendStream.error (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:275:17)
at SendStream.onStatError (/Users/Bill/Documents/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:392:12)
```

If anyone has any solutions that would be great. I have many promises in my project that are all extremely similar and those are all working great but I just can't get my head around this one.

Comment: Line 12 is `return next();`?

Comment: I really wonder why you don't get a warning about the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) in `validate_session`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the mix of promise-based code (`Session.validate_session`) with callback-based code (`next`). It would be expected that the `next()` call either is not asynchronous (doesn't create any promises) or *returns* that promise, which it doesn't (blame express).

There are two ways to avoid the warning:

- Let express do the error handling, and call `next` with an error if one occurs. In this case, you can use the [`.asCallback` method](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html):

  ```
  Middleware.is_authenticated = function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.system_session == undefined || req.system_session.login_status == false)
          var promise = Promise.reject(new Error('invalid_session'));
      else
          var promise = Session.validate_session(req.system_session, req.ip, req.headers['user-agent']);

      promise.asCallback(next);
  };
  ```
- As the [warning explanation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it) says, you can explicitly `return null` instead of returning the `undefined` value that `next()` yields:

  ```
  Middleware.is_authenticated = function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.system_session == undefined || req.system_session.login_status == false)
          var promise = Promise.reject(new Error('invalid_session'));
      else
          var promise = Session.validate_session(req.system_session, req.ip, req.headers['user-agent'])
          .catch(function(err) {
              req.system_session.destroy();
              throw err;
          });

      promise.then(function(session) {
          next();
          return null;
      }, function(err) {
          res.status(401).send({errors: true, error: err.message, session: req.system_session}).end();
      });
  };
  ```